Two elements with the same name for xml path()
I'm trying to create an XML using T-SQL (SQL Server 2019) with two elements that have the same name, i already did some research and found somewhat of a workaround but the result still isn't what I'm hoping for.
This is what I've tried so far:
select
'A' as [Test/Route/Client/value],
'',
'B' as [Test/Route/Client/value]
for xml path('test'), type

This is the workaround i've read about (using this you can create a new node with the same names):
'',

But the problem is, the result for this is this one:
<test>
  <Test>
    <Route>
      <Client>
        <value>A</value>
      </Client>
    </Route>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Route>
      <Client>
        <value>B</value>
      </Client>
    </Route>
  </Test>
</test>

and my desired result would be like this:
<test>
  <Test>
    <Route>
      <Client>
        <value>A</value>
        <value>B</value>
      </Client>
    </Route>
  </Test>
</test>

Is there any way to do this (so basically an array)?

possible duplicate of SQL FOR XML to generate multiple same name nodes

nope, the solution there doesn't work for me, i already tried it

Don't generate the nested structure manually, use subqueries instead, also, please provide the data you're working with

@Dave28 I also tried, and they do work.

The problem is you are using multiple node names in your alias. As a result '' with no alias means '' at the root level; so you are exiting any other nodes (in this case, Client, Route, and Test). To use the method you use, you'd need to tell SQL Server that the blank string belongs in your Client Node:
SELECT 'A' AS [Test/Route/Client/value],
       '' AS [Test/Route/Client],
       'B' AS [Test/Route/Client/value]
FOR XML PATH('test'), TYPE;

Otherwise you could build your XML using subqueries. For example:
SELECT (SELECT 'A' AS value, '',
               'B' AS value
        FOR XML PATH('Client'), ROOT('Route'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('Test'), ROOT('test'), TYPE;


this does indeed work, Thank You for your help Siggemannen

My name is Thom, @Dave28 .

There is another and better method to compose XML for your scenario.
It allows to do it "visually" via computed constructors in SQL Server's XQuery.
If needed, the "A" and "B" values could be sourced from T-SQL variables instead of being hard-coded.
SQL
SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).query('
    element test {
        element Test {
            element Route {
                element Client {
                    element value {"A"},
                    element value {"B"}
    }}}}
');

Output
<test>
  <Test>
    <Route>
      <Client>
        <value>A</value>
        <value>B</value>
      </Client>
    </Route>
  </Test>
</test>


That's pretty neat!

You say "better"; what makes this method better? Can you elaborate?

@ThomA, It is "visual" XML composition ease vs. not so obvious SELECT ... FOR XML PATH... statement. Additionally, the alias way has a length limitation up to 128 chars. So, when XML is deeply nested and has namespace prefixes, it just doesn't work at all.

Yes, I can see it's visually different but what makes it "better"? Is the syntax more performant, for example?
